# UIDatePicker help please

Tags: iphone, uidatepicker, nslocale

I have an UIDatePicker that displays the date in an UITableViewCell.

I would like to define to the datePicker to change the date format in the UITableViewCell according to the device international settings.
How can I define it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [`NSLocale` class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html).